# Plot shifted t-distribution with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the density curve of a t-distribution with mean = 3 and df = 1.5 using ggplot2. However it is supposed to be symmetric around 3, so I can not use the noncentrality parameter.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 10)), aes(x = x)) +
stat_function(fun = dt, args = list(df = 1.5))
```

Is there a way to simply shift the distribution along the x-axis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could also make a custom function for your shifted t-distribution:

```
custom <- function(x) {dt(x - 3, 1.5)}
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 10)), aes(x = x)) +
    stat_function(fun = custom)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to just change the labels instead:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 10)), aes(x = x)) +
    stat_function(fun = dt, args = list(df = 1.5)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 5, 10), labels = c(3, 8, 13))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a function `dt.scaled` in the metRology package, which in addition to the df, lets you specify the mean and scale.

Relevant code:

```
dt.scaled <- function(x, df, mean = 0, sd = 1, ncp, log = FALSE) {
        if (!log) stats::dt((x - mean)/sd, df, ncp = ncp, log = FALSE)/sd
        else stats::dt((x - mean)/sd, df, ncp = ncp, log = TRUE) - log(sd)
}
```